# sql: sort rows using a running sum column

Tags: sql, sorting

I have a table which contains bank statements. In each row I have the date of the bank transaction, the amount, and the running balance (the balance after the processing the transaction).
I also have the current balance, which equals the running balance of the last trx.

The problem is that the transactions are not sorted according to posting order. I would like to sort them, using the information on each row and the following natural logic:

After sorting, for each row, the running balance will be the 'starting balance' for the next row, where starting balance for a row = running balance - transaction amount. The rows need to be sorted by date also, of course.

For example, say all transaction are posted on the same day. 
Running balance = 0

Trx 1: amount  50, running balance -51
Trx 2: amount 51, running balance 0
Trx 3: amount 60, running balance -101.

So the order (from latest to first):
Trx 2
Trx 1
Trx 3

It's possible that there will be several valid orders. In that case I would suffice for any valid ordering.

Is this possible in SQL (any variant)? I though about doing this using self joins and partitions, but I'm bounded to making the number of joins equal to the maximal number of trxs posted in a single day, while I would like a solution for any number of trxs posted in a single day.

Comment: I don't see any type of code in your question. Have you tried anything? If so, please post the **code**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a real timestamp column that defines the order of transactions, this is quite easy in standard ANSI SQL:

```
select account_id, 
       transaction_id, 
       transaction_time,
       sum(amount) over (partition by account_id order by transaction_time) as running_total
from transactions
order by account_id, transaction_time;
```

If you don't store the "execution order" of the transactions, there is no way you can get a proper running balance.

The above will work (at least) with Postgres, Oracle, DB2, SQL Server 2012, Teradata

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do an ORDER BY clause that matches your function to get the running total.

Example:

```
SELECT a.AccountID, sum(t.Amount)
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN Transaction t on a.AccountID = t.AccountID
GROUP BY a.AccountID
ORDER BY sum(t.Amount) DESC
```

You could then add more ORDER BY clauses to order further from there

Comment: I'm wasn't able to define an explicit order by function. I was only able to define what a valid order is.

Comment: Well if you aren't able to use an ORDER BY for some reason, you can't order your query. You're going to need to be more specific. If you're talking about reordering the actual rows in the table, that can't be done. That's what the ORDER BY clause is for.